# Windows repair console, impossible?

Tags: windows, installation, ms-dos

I found an old Windows XP SP2 in my -trash- cd can and tried it on a 30 GB FAT32 partition.

Installation went fine till the copying operation was completed and XP asked for reboot. After that either it starts over again or throws invalid disk.

Starting over is an infinite loop the only way I see is to choose the "Repair console" but I'm not used to a DOS box.

Can anyone help me through this harmful installation?

Comment: This should be on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

When you boot off the CD you actually do not want to hit the R key right away.  First hit Enter to start Windows setup.  Accept the EULA.  Then existing installations will be found.  Select your previous install then hit the R key.